# Magento remove reward points on Credit Memo

Tags: magento

when we credit memo an order the reward points are not being removed – is there a way to set this so it does remove the points when a credit is processed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to deal with the reward points manually since there is no way to have this work automatically. The customer may already have used the credit points by the time of your refund.